# How to read data from database & write it on a txt file?

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve data from the server database using windows services on a text file?Can i do that?How will i do that?I mean i know to create a window service but i am confused with the SQL connection and  file writing part where to execute it?i have tried something

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunSchedule();
    }
    public static void RunSchedule()
    {
        string path = Path.GetFullPath("d:\\MyTest") + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm") + "_Log.txt";
        try
        {


            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path);
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=s_a;Password=sa56ta112;");
                String sql = @"SELECT Id,UserName, Email,Password,CreatedDate
                  FROM Register";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
                com.CommandText = sql;
                //com.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                StreamWriter tw = File.AppendText("d:\\MyTest");
                SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                tw.WriteLine("Id,UserName,Email,Password,CreatedDate");
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    tw.Write(reader["Id"].ToString());
                    tw.Write(" , " + reader["UserName"].ToString());
                    tw.Write(" , " + reader["Email"].ToString());
                    tw.Write(" , " + reader["Password"].ToString());
                    tw.Write(" , " + reader["CreatedDate"].ToString());
                }
                tw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                tw.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
                tw.Close();
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorLogPath = @"D:\MyTest.txt";
            File.AppendAllText(errorLogPath, Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

am i doing it correct? Please guide me.

Comment: Why not dump the output to a string first? Similar to how you're doing with the error file.
`File.WriteAllText (@"D:\path.txt", yourString);` -  would be how I would do it.

Comment: Do you get an error? Is the result somehow different from what you expected? You need to provide a bit more information on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Right now it is hard to understand your problem. Can you explain a little better what you are trying to achieve and where the error/problem you are having is happening?

Comment: A text file is getting created with mytest name but on the inside i am getting "Access to the path 'd:\MyTest' is denied."

Comment: ok as i told you that  i am trying to create a windows service that i want to run on the server computer to capture the data from a particular table and store in the txt file as log of the day.In this thing i am confused with where to start with.did some RnD on the net and came up with the above code using my knowledge and some help from those articles.

Comment: In this case your problem has to do with access-permissions on your file-system, not with any DB. So you can ommit the DB-specific parts of your question, maybe you´ll get better help when your problem is quite more specific. However: DO you have access to that directory?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.Read())

{
    row = new DataRow();
    row.ItemArray = new object[reader.FieldCount];
    reader.GetValues(row.ItemArray);
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        streamWriter.Write((string)item + "\t");
    }
    streamWriter.WriteLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get "Access to the path 'd:\MyTest' is denied." error than go to the txt file properties in the solution explorer and than change the Copy to output directory property from Do not copy into Copy if newer or Copy always